# How to correctly guarantee the high availability requirement for a WSO2 MB profile cluster?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker

I have the following doubt relating how to correctly set up a WSO2 MB cluster respecting the requirements of high availability. I am following this official guide: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+Message+Broker+Profile#ClusteringtheMessageBrokerProfile-Testingthecluster

So I will have a two nodes WSO2 MB profile cluster. Now my doubt is related to the **high availability** concept (basically: if a single node is not working, the cluster should still works).

I have two nodes cluster, each node run on a specific server having a specific IP address, something like this

**NODE 1 with the IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.1**

**NODE 2 with the IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.2**

So lets suppose that I want publish a message into a queue defined on this cluster. I suppose that I can send the message indifferently to one of these 2 nodes (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion).

If this is the situation: how can I guarantee the **high availability** requirement? Can I simply put both my nodes under a load balancer? so that if one node doesn't work, the request is directed to the other

Is it a correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you have both of the EI instances with MB profile clustering where the two servers have cluster coordination configured on JDBC or Hazelcast level, with the above-mentioned approach you will guarantee the high availability of the service.

You can make sure to follow the below provide additional precautions to make sure both servers do not go down for the same reason at ones.

- Have the two servers in two separate instances rather than having
  offset in the same instance.
- You can configure the load balancer to
  work in Active-Passive or Active-Active mode if you are deployed on a
  cloud provider like AWS you can add configurations to redeploy the instances of the health check is failed for a given amount of time.